# About logisticGD. NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python, I want to use logistic GD. but I have in trouble.
when I want using 100000 iterations to get the beta, it shows:NameError: name 'x' is not defined

```
def sigmond (x):
    return (1/(1+np.exp(-x)))


def Gradient_Descent_Algo(X, t, beta, alpha, m, numIterations) & sigmond (x) :   
    XTrans = X.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        # predicted values from the model
        model = sigmond(np.dot(X, beta))
        loss_temp = model - t
        # calculte the loss function
        loss1=np.log (sigmond(np.dot(x, beta)))* t
        loss2=np.log(1-sigmond(np.dot(x,beta))) * 1-t
        loss = np.sum(loss1+loss2) / m
        # save all the loss function values at each step
        loss_total[i]= loss
        # calcualte the gradient using matrix representation
        gradient = np.dot(XTrans, loss_temp) / m
        # update the parameters simulteneously with learning rate alpha
        beta = beta - alpha * gradient
        # save all the estimated parametes at each step
        beta_total[i,:]= beta.transpose()
    return beta,loss
    return (1/(1+np.exp(-x)))
```

Comment: Please check the code posted, it should be giving you a SyntaxError, not NameError, because  `& sigmond (x)` makes no sense there.

Comment: Please paste your entire script

Comment: And a stack trace showing *where* you get the error.

Comment: The line `loss1=...` uses a lowercase x

Comment: as the second return (never reached!?)